# What is the recommended way to integrate AngularJS front end client with Ruby on Rails back end in terms of frequency of commits?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, integration, api-design

I was wondering, when you're integrating Angular front end with RoR back end, how often should you commit updates?

Having that with angular you can store any updates in your model and then commit/save changes on some event that is not immediate, I was wondering how often is it recommended to perform updates?

To further explain, if I have a page with 50 small photos on it, and they can each be liked or disliked, should I update the database on every like, or should I aggregate likes and then update on some exiting event?

If I am to commit every update should I wait for any response, or should I just update model manually and chill?

Thanks

Comment: Safest and easiest to update each one when event occurs

Comment: So, going further with the analogy, if I like one out of the 50 photos, and I send the update, should I reload the whole data set from the server response, or should I just update the scope model?

Comment: Should be able to simply update scope model within success of server update. Unless you absolutely need to update what other users have done but probably not just for `likes`

Comment: ah, okay, so on server response, I should only update the scope model with whatever's changed according to the response data?

Comment: I understand what you mean, thank you for following up.